# iOS Safari: use actual browser size (independent of eventual toolbar) for CSS styling

Tags: html, ios, css

When `height: 100vh` is provided to iOS Safari, it [uses the full iPhone screen size](http://nicolas-hoizey.com/2015/02/viewport-height-is-taller-than-the-visible-part-of-the-document-in-some-mobile-browsers.html) instead of the visible part (excluding the toolbar, if currently visible).

I search a lot but didn't find any proper workaround for it.

Is there a (preferably CSS-only) way to set the height of an element to the size of the visible screen - no matter if a toolbar is displayed or not?

I want to center an HTML element both, vertically and horizontally, while its width adapts to the screen width as well.

I am currently using the following piece of CSS, which works great - except for mobile iOS Safari (I left out the vendor prefixes for the sake of simplicity):

```
.vertical-center{
  min-height: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: @BhojendraNepal `height: 100vh` does not work (please see the link above): The height represents the whole screen, including the toolbars - so the resulting page is larger than the visible area, and the scroolbars are visible

Comment: the linked post shows that a bug, then do you think you could get an answer here?

Comment: @BhojendraNepal yes, maybe a workaround or another approach

Answer (score 0):

Someone shared a possible solution in a comment on my blog post.

He recommended using `min-height: calc(100% - 0);`.

I didn't try it yet.